# How to connect java to a website/webhost database

Tags: java, mysql

Ok, I have been trying to connect to a database from a client program to a web server using java, and I will be very specific in this question.

I am using "ServersFree.com" as the web host that is hosting my database.
I am using the latest java run time environment and the latest java SDK (JavaSE-1.7 as of the time of this writing).
I am using windows 7 Home Premium as my platform for writing this program.

Here is what I am trying to do to attempt the connection to this web server and the database within:

```
        try
        {
            String host = "jdbc:mysql://server17.serversfree.com/database";
            String username = "admin";
            String password = "example";

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("There is an error with the SQL database: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

I have done some research for this and it turns out I might need a driver for the connection (seeing as I am getting an error from the output like this: "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://server17.serversfree.com/database")

Output:

```
There is an error with the SQL database: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://server17.serversfree.com/database
```

My questions are 1.) what driver is this program talking about that I don't have? and 2.) Where should I go or look to understand this problem?

Note: I noticed some people recommended not to use Microsoft's driver for this problem, and I tried looking for a jar file called "sqljdbc4.jar", but I had no luck finding it.

Any help would be appreciated. (anything that could point me to the right direction.)

Comment: Driver is the implementation of the JDBC interfaces used to communicate between Java and DB. Search for MySql drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please download the suitable driver from following link. You have to download the driver for operating system from which you are trying to connect.Inyour case this is windows.

[Mysql Driver for windows](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

the file would be just a JAR. file which you need to include in your classpath while executing the program.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to download the official JDBC driver for MySQL ([ConnectorJ](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)).

`SQLJDBC` seems to be for SQL databases, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You may need `mysql-connector-java-{version}-bin.jar` in your classpath.

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://server17.serversfree.com/database", "admin",
                    "example");
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("There is an error with the SQL database: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```